# how to run static files in pythonanywhere hosting?

Tags: django, pythonanywhere, django-staticfiles

I'm trying to upload my project via pythonanywhere but I always get failed to load static files I tried to download it by the static files section of web tab that exists into pythonanywhere and also I got failed you can see what I did [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehwj7.png), I will show you all details that I did to help you to understand what could you give me the help through it:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
# STATIC_ROOT = "/home/abdelhamedabdin96/website/website/static/index"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
# MAIN_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
# STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#     os.path.join(MAIN_DIR, 'static'),
# )
```

and in urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you haven't run collect static command, You need to run this command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

**Here its explanation** for more info vist to the [django official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/)

django.contrib.staticfiles collects static files from each of your applications (and any other places you specify) into a single location that can easily be served in production.

Answer (score 0):

Try use Aws console and its very cheap. I see bugs on Pythonanywhere. ie. Scheduler and a lot of limitations.